# How manage to get an automated build server with jenkins for projects in Delphi

Tags: delphi, jenkins, msbuild

*In a nutshell, how manage to get an automated build server with jenkins or other, to build several Delphi's projetcs using MSBuild?*

I am currently a trainee in a company. I have managed to find a solution to migrate and change the old SCM software : PVCS to SVN. But they are using old shell scripts and Cygwin to build with several options to compile/release all or certain Delphi projects and produce DLL and EXE. I wanted firstly to use Jenkins to try to reproduce the same mechanism, but I am not sure it is the best way to deal with this. I have tried to set a free-style job and a multibranch pipeline. The first is ok to build one project but the latter is not a success, I don't know groovy...

I am not interested in the test part of the continuous integration I just want to have an automated build for several Delphi projects.
I don't know how to deal with this. Maybe the best way is to make as much as jenkins' jobs as there is delphi's projects? But how to control them after?
I have read about Maven and Ant but I am not sure it is relevant in my case.

Any advices are welcomed

Answer (score 2):

You can create simple jobs `"free-style job"` or `"pipelines"`. The pipelines are more powerful, but more complicated if you are starting.

You can start by creating a Job for each project. Then you can chain projects with different jenkins options. When a Job finish the other job start. See image following image.

[image]

You can also use to compile an existing [plugin for existing RAD Studio for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/RAD+Studio+Plugin). Use it in `"free-style job"`.

The other option is to use pipelines, but you should know something about Groovy. 
For example, a simple pipeline with several steps would be this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage: Show message Hola Mundo') {
            steps {
                echo 'Paso 1. Hola Mundo'
            }
        }
        stage('Download source from GIT') {
            steps {
                echo 'Downloading...'
                git([url: 'https://XXX_repository_xxxx.git/gitProject', branch: 'master', credentialsId: 'a234234a-344e-2344-9440-423444xxxxxx'])
            }
        }
        stage('Executing MSDOS file (BAT)') {
            steps {
                echo '-- Sample Executing BAT file'
                bat '"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\19.0\\bin\\rsvars.bat"'
            }
        }
        stage('MSBuild a Delphi project') {
            steps {
                println("************ EXECUTING MSBUILD ******************")
                echo '-- Lanzar la ejecución de rsVars ---------'
                bat '"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\19.0\\bin\\rsvars.bat"'
                echo '-- MSBuils del proyecto TestLauncher -------'
                bat '"c:\\local\\AutomaticTestsProject\\compilar.bat"'                
            }    
        }
        stage('Execute a test project (EXE)') {
            steps {
                bat 'c:\\local\\AutomaticTestsProject\\BIN\\AutomaticTestsProject.exe'
            }
        }
        stage('Send emeil') {
            steps {
                emailext (
                    subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME} ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'",
                    body: """<p>Check console output at <a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME}</a></p>""",
                    to: "destinatary@hotmail.com",
                    from: "JenkinsMachine@mail.com" )
            }
        }
    }
}
```